# GAE - django manage.py problem

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Hello i am trying to use GAE with django but i am facing a problem.
I used the testapp and i made a new app. Lets say it test, with the command manage.py startapp test.

Then i made some models and i tried to use the command manage.py sql test.

The problem is that it does not work and gives me this.

```
WARNING  2011-05-26 21:15:19,855 datastore_file_stub.py:657] Could not read datastore data
 from C:\Users\faust\Desktop\appdja\project\django-testapp\.gaedata\datastore
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: How are you using django in GAE, using django non-rel?

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, that's a warning. Assuming your models are correct, the message will go away after you actually store something into your backend (That's when your .gaedata\datastore will get populated).